# How to compare if a string is of less value than other string flutter

Tags: string, flutter, compare

I need help to compare 2 strings that i have and i want to check if one of them has less value than the other so i can throw an alert message.
My code is as followed

```
if (dateEntered <= date) {
  print("DateEntered wrong $dateEntered");
}
```

The error is that

The operator '<=' isn't defined for the class 'String'.
Try defining the operator '<='

Thank you for your time

Comment: When you say 'less value' what exactly do you mean? That the amount of characters in the string differ by a certain amount or that the strings don't match entirely?

Comment: for example i want to compare 2 dates so i want to see if the entered date isnt before the current day

Comment: Use `DateTime.parse(String)`

Comment: Didnt work :( "The operator '<=' isn't defined for the class 'DateTime'.
Try defining the operator '<='"

Comment: Use the helper methods `isBefore` and `isAfter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're comparing dates you can use the [`DateTime`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) class to generate new dates and then use the helper method [isBefore](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-core/DateTime/isBefore.html) to do the comparison. You can also use other helper methods like `isAfter` and `difference`

```
 var now = new DateTime.now();
 var earlier = now.subtract(const Duration(seconds: 5));

  if(earlier.isBefore(now)){
    print('Earlier is 5 seconds before now, so earlier.isBefore(now) is true');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to compare dates, you need to do something like this,

```
    var df1 = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').parse('22-10-2019');
    var df2 = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').parse('25-10-2019');
    print(df1.isBefore(df2).toString());
```

Output: true

---

Edit : you will have to use install [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl#-readme-tab-) package inside `pubspec.yaml` to use code above,

```
dependencies:
  intl: ^0.16.0
```